# Does Google Maps API Track Distance By Different Modes of Travel using Mobile GPS?

Tags: google-maps

Google maps timeline reports shows the location we have visited and the distance we have walked or traveled in a vehicle. This is tracked by using mobile GPS. Can we get these details via Google Maps API - the total distance traveled split by different modes of travel?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the calculation of distances between two locations, you may specify the `travel mode` in Google Maps `distance-matrix` API.

By default, distances are calculated for `driving mode`.

```
function initMap() {
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds;

        var origin = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
        var destination = {lat: -25.34470, lng: 131.05121};

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044},
          zoom: 12
        });

        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService;
        service.getDistanceMatrix({
          origins: [origin],
          destinations: [destination],
          travelMode: 'DRIVING',
          unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
          avoidHighways: false,
          avoidTolls: false
        }, function(response, status) {          
            var originList = response.originAddresses;
            var destinationList = response.destinationAddresses;
            var outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');
            outputDiv.innerHTML = '';
          }
        });
```

}

**RESPONSE**

A successful call to the `Distance Matrix service` returns a `DistanceMatrixResponse`

*sample*

```
   {
      "originAddresses": [ "Greenwich, Greater London, UK"],
      "destinationAddresses": [ "Stockholm County, Sweden"],
      "rows": [{
        "elements": [{
          "status": "OK",
          "duration": {
            "value": 70778,
            "text": "19 hours 40 mins"
          },
          "distance": {
            "value": 1887508,
            "text": "1173 mi"
          }
        }]
      }]
    }
```

Ref: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/distance-matrix
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix

Answer (score 0):

we can request distance data for different travel modes for the calculation of distances between two location on map you need to mention the **travel mode**  in the request URL of **Distance Matrix API**.

refer this link for more clarification:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/distance-matrix